Illustration about a concept in the Modern C book is needed
As found in this book, Modern C by Jens Gustedt:

In our examples so far, we have seen names for two different features:
objectsC, i and A, and functionsC, main and printf. In contrast to object or function declarations, where several are
allowed for the same identifier, definitions of objects or functions
must be unique. That is, for a C program to be operational, any object
or function that is used must have a definition (otherwise the
execution would not know where to look for them), and there must be no
more than one definition (otherwise the execution could become
inconsistent).

It's mentioned that several declarations are allowed for the same identifier, however I tried to do:
    // Declarations
    int i;
    int i;

but got this error in the terminal:
try.c: In function 'main':
try.c:7:9: error: redeclaration of 'i' with no linkage
     int i;
         ^
try.c:6:9: note: previous declaration of 'i' was here 
     int i;
         ^ 


This question is similar to: How do I use extern to share variables between source files?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

As for trying to declare local variables inside main without defining them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24245318/understanding-the-extern-keyword-in-c

I'm not asking about the usage of the keyword extern.
My main issue is that the author suggested that multiple declarations are welcome, while what appears to me is that they are erroneous, as I tried.

If you declare a variable without extern keyword, that is also a definition.

Ah, I see. Thanks, Gerhard.

Answer
int i; inside a function is a definition. That is why the compiler gives you an error for repeating it.
Supplement
int i; outside a function is a tentative definition. In spite of its name, a tentative definition is not a definition, in the same way that a prospective employee on a job interview is not actually an employee. Since it is not a definition, it may be repeated without generating an error.
The rules for which declarations are definitions and which are not are somewhat complicated and are not stated in a single place in the C standard. Students learning C simply have to learn them over time.
Since a tentative definition is not a definition, it may be repeated throughout a translation unit. If a translation unit has a tentative definition for an identifier but does not have an actual definition for the identifier, a definition will be generated for it.
Corrections
This statement quoted in the question is flawed:

In contrast to object or function declarations, where several are allowed for the same identifier, definitions of objects or functions must be unique.

“Contrasting” declarations with definitions is flawed because a definition is a declaration. Definitions are a subset of declarations, not a separate thing.
It is also not technically correct to say that definitions must be unique. For an identifier for an object or a function, the C standard does not define what happens if there are multiple definitions. That does not mean you cannot have multiple definitions, just that the standard does not say what happens then. For one example, historically, some C implementations have specified that definitions generated by tentative definitions are supported and are resolved to a single definition.
For a typedef name, the C standard says a definition may be repeated. (C 2018 6.7 3: “… a typedef name may be redefined to denote the same type as it currently does, provided that
type is not a variably modified type…”)

Nice explanation for a confusing part of C.
